# Gradle flatdir on windows gets: Could not find property 'url'

Tags: java, gradle

Trying to get a flatdir repository to work on my windows pc.

But it fails with the error below when I try to list the repositories.

Listing the archives shows the jar.

Running the check repository task shows that the directory exists.

Running uploadArchves seems to do nothing (no files in the local repository).

Thanks.

Edit: Turns out that the flatdir does not have an url property, so that explains the build error, but still nothing is in the flatdir directory after an uploadArchives.

How do you get the uploadArchives to actually do something?

Edit: Here the build file that worked:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    flatDir {
        name "localRepository"
        dirs "d:/ray/gradlerepository/"
    }
}
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        add project.repositories.localRepository
    }
}
```

This is the original stuff:

```
    D:\ray\dev\conradapps\lib1>gradle mLR
    :myListRepositories
    Repositories:
    Name: BintrayJCenter; url: https://jcenter.bintray.com/
    :myListRepositories FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:

   Build file 'D:\ray\dev\conradapps\lib1\build.gradle' line: 15

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':myListRepositories'.
    > `Could not find property 'url'` on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositorie
    s.DefaultFlatDirArtifactRepository_Decorated@a7a0831.
```

Build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    //jcenter()
    flatDir {
        name "localRepository"
        dirs "d:/ray/gradlerepository/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
task myListRepositories << {
    println "Repositories:"
    project.repositories.each { println "Name: " + it.name + "; url: " + it.url }
}
task myListArchives << {
    println "Archives Artifacts: " + configurations.archives.allArtifacts
}
task myCheckRepository << {
    if(new File("d:/ray/gradlerepository").exists()) println("file exists");
        else println("file not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/FlatDirectoryArtifactRepository.html) FlatDirectoryArtifactRepository doesn't have an url property (but it has a `dirs`), though you're trying to access it here

```
project.repositories.each { println "Name: " + it.name + "; url: " + it.url }
```

This is working for jcenter, because it's a maven repo(just another repository type) and it has such a property.

You can modify your task, making it displaying only the common repositories fields of the [ArtifactRepository interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/ArtifactRepository.html) or add some logic to check the repository type, in order to print repository info differently for different repository types and to prevent access to the fields, which do not exist.

Comment: took off the it.url, works fine. but still nothing uploaded to the repository.

Comment: I don't see in your build.script configuration for uploadArchives task. Just declare some repository is just enough to download dependencies, not to publish them. To upload em, you have to add this repo as a uploadArchives { repositories { add project.repositories.localRepository } }

Comment: If you've done it (specified uploadArchive configuration), then you have to update your question with some additional info, like a full build.script. Because from now, it's not an exception you've described in your question.

Comment: that is the full script. don't know about specifying uploadArchive configuration.

Comment: Read the users guide about it. You have to add uploadArchives{ repositories { add project.repositories.localRepository } } to publish artifacts into your local repository https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#N13951

Comment: wonderful, i now have an unspecified jar, some xml and some sha's!